# Disable entities/redirection in EasyAdmin Bundle for specific Roles

Tags: redirect, permissions, entity, easyadmin

i`m trying to set permissions for some entities in the EasyAdmin Symfony Bundle.

```
menu:
  - { entity: 'Team', permission: ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN'] }
 entities:
Team:
  class: App\Entity\Team
  list:
    item_permission: ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN']
  show:
  ...
```

When I login as ROLE_USES, as expected the Team Entity is not showing in the menu, but I am still redirected to the Team Entity:

`localhost/admin/?action=list&entity=Team`

[image]

It is just not allowed to see or edit the entity but it is still accessible

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> EasyAdmin Events
>   PRE_LIST, POST_LIST

Use Any based On Your Requirement 
Ex

```
private $tokenStorage;
private $authorizationChecker;
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
}
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        EasyAdminEvents::PRE_LIST => 'onPrelist',
    ];
}


public function onPrelist(GenericEvent $event)
{
    $config = $event->getSubject();
    if ($config['class'] == <Entity>::class) {
        $this->denyAccessUnless();
    }
}
private function denyAccessUnless()
{
    if (!$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(<ROLE To Check>)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
}
```

More Events : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#customization-based-on-symfony-events

Answer (score -1):

the answer is simple:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/menu-configuration.html#changing-the-backend-index-page

setting another entity to default